# 'import keras.layers' gives No module named keras error, yet it is perfectly fine if it is run in cmd

Tags: keras

Running pytest complains about the issue (the import statement is in test_nn.py). But if I were to run 'python' in cmd and directly run the exact same import statement, it gives no error.

It used to be fine.

[image]

Comment: What version of Python does `pytest` use, and what version of Python do you get from cmd?

Comment: When I run pytest, it says 3.6.6. The default python version (if I run python from cmd) is 3.6.6 as well. I have 3.7 version from Anaconda. In the PATH system variable python.exe from normal python (ie; 3.6.6) is listed at top most.

Comment: That screenshot says the error is `NameError: name 'keras' is not defined`, which means you haven't imported keras at all.

Comment: No, that is after I edited. There seems to be other problems with how the import is written as well. Eg; I can't write import keras.layers, but can write from keras import layers. So I edited them and the message changed.

Comment: I used to be able to run 'where keras' and where tensorflow/numpy/ etc.. as well. Now non of those work.

Comment: Alright, I just reinstalled keras and tensorflow. Both imports are working now.